# SELECT the correct ODD if the answer is false

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 table in my Database named : `questions`, `answerquestion`, `odds`

The first one (Questions) has a list of questions

```
+=========================+
|   ID   |    question    | 
+=========================+
|   1    |    Bla Bla     |
|   2    |    question    |
|   3    | Other Question |
+-------------------------+
```

The second one (AnswerQuestion) has a the answer of users of a specific question

```
+==================================================+
|   ID   | idQuestion | idOdd | idUser | isCorrect |
+==================================================+
|   1    |    4       |     2 |     5  |     0     |
|   2    |    3       |     1 |     1  |     1     |
|   3    |    1       |     3 |     10 |     0     |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

The third one (Odds) has the odds of question with the correct one

```
+============================================+
|   ID   |    odd   | idQuestion | isCorrect |
+============================================+
|   1    |    One   |          1 |     0     |
|   2    |    Two   |          1 |     1     |
|   3    |   Three  |          1 |     0     |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

So, to get the answers of a specific user I user this query :

```
SELECT * FROM answerquestion a, question q, odds o
WHERE a.IdUser = :id AND a.IdOdd = o.ID AND a.IdQuestion = q.ID
```

It's work fine, but I want to get the correct odd if the answer of user is false
and for that I use the `IF` statement on SQL, The query is :

```
SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1;
SELECT DISTINCT IF(o.isCorrect = 0, o.Corr.TheCorr, o.odd), q.Question
FROM answerquestion a, odds o, question q,
  ( SELECT o.odd AS TheCorr FROM odds o, question q WHERE o.isCorrect = 1 AND o.IdQuestion = q.ID) AS Corr
WHERE a.IdUser = 5
AND q.ID = a.idQuestion
AND a.IdOdd = o.ID
```

The problem on this query is on the answer is false, it's give me all the correct answer of all the question and duplicate the question

Example:

```
Question ID 4 'Bla Bla' | Correct odd of Question ID 1
Question ID 4 'Bla Bla' | Correct odd of Question ID 2
Question ID 4 'Bla Bla' | Correct odd of Question ID 3
Question ID 4 'Bla Bla' | Correct odd of Question ID 4
Question ID 4 'Bla Bla' | Correct odd of Question ID 5
```

I want if the answer of Question ID 4, I need to get just the correct odd of it

```
Question ID 4 'Bla Bla' | Correct odd of Question ID 4
```

Any help ?

Comment: Please provide other tables, if we don't know the schema, we can't help

Comment: @DDS I added it sir

Comment: Example? How is that an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using proper JOIN is what is needed. Not sure what columns should be selected but that is easy to fix.

```
SELECT q.id, q.question, o.odd as correct, o2.odd as user_odd
FROM question q
JOIN AnswerQuestion a ON a.idQuestion = q.id
JOIN Odds o ON o.questionID = q.id AND o.isCorrect = 1
JOIN Odds o2 ON o2.id = a.idOdd
WHERE a.idUser = 5
```

Comment: Thanks for your help sir, my problem is I want to get the correct odds if the answer of user is incorrect, your query get the incorrect odds of a question ( more than one ) I hope that you can understand my bad English

Comment: @ThaSayou I changed check on `isCorrect` to 1.

Comment: I try this query `SELECT * FROM question q
JOIN AnswerQuestion a ON a.idQuestion = q.id
JOIN Odds o ON o.questionID = q.id
AND o.isCorrect =1
WHERE a.IdUser =5` this query return the correct odd of a question, but I want to show the answer odd of user + the correct odd. any help ?